# How to disable Isapi module

Tags: iis-7.5, isapi

I have a web-site for which I disabled the `ISAPI-dll` handler mapping. see picture
[image]

now I'd think when I access any .dll file it shall be server as a regular file and I would be able to save it. But it doesn't work, I'm getting a 403.1 error when I try to download a dll file from a subfolder, and yes I made sure the isapi-extension is disabled on that sub-folder as well.

This is the error. Why the isapi filter works? what else shall be disabled?
Thx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well, it turns out this module was enabled in the web.config file by another developer. I thought IIS would show me that it is enabled in web.config but it didn't. 
After I removed that line from web.config everything started to work fine.